# Object Hierarchy employee program - dereferencing pointer for cout

Tags: c++, polymorphism, virtual-functions

I am new to c++ and am working on a project for class. I know I that some of my functions are not correct. I am trying to get to a point to where I can at least see the output to continue working on it. I have included a brief description of that I am trying to do.

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Employee
{
protected:
    char* name[50];
public:

Employee()
{

}

Employee(char* name)
{
    strcpy(name, name);
}

char* getName()
{
    return *name;
}
void setName(char* name)
{
    name = name;
}

/*virtual ~Employee()
{
    delete[] name;
}*/

virtual void print() = 0;


};

class HourlyEmployee : public Employee
{
private:
    float HourlySalary;
public:


HourlyEmployee()
{
    HourlySalary = 0;
}
HourlyEmployee(char* name, float HourlySalary)
{
    name = name;
    HourlySalary = HourlySalary;
}
double getHourlySalary()
{
    return HourlySalary;
    //cout << "What is your Hourly Salary" << endl;
    //cin >> HourlySalary;
}
void setHourlySalary(double HourlySalary)
{

}
void print()
{
    cout << "Hourly Employee Name: " << &name << endl
        << "Salary: " << &HourlySalary << "per hour" << endl;
}

};

class SalariedEmployee : public Employee

{
private:
    float MonthlySalary;

public:

SalariedEmployee()
{
    MonthlySalary = 0;
}
SalariedEmployee(char* name, float MonthlySalary)
{

}
double getMonthlyySalary()
{
    return MonthlySalary;
    //cout << "What is your Hourly Salary" << endl;
    //cin >> MonthlySalary;
}
void setMonthlySalary(double MonthlySalary)
{

}
void print()
{
        cout << "Hourly Employee Name: " << name << endl
            << "Salary: " << MonthlySalary << "per month" << endl;
}

};

int main() {
SalariedEmployee* S = new SalariedEmployee();
SalariedEmployee S1("Joe Bob", '4500');

HourlyEmployee* H = new HourlyEmployee();
HourlyEmployee H1("Jim Bob", '20');

S1.print();
H1.print();

delete S, H;

system("pause");
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the description of your exercise I concluded that you're asking for something like this:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Employee
{
protected:
    char name[50];
public:

    Employee()
    {

    }

    Employee(char* name)
    {
        strncpy_s(this->name, 49, name, 49);
    }

    char* getName()
    {
        return this->name;
    }

    void setName(char *name)
    {
        strncpy_s(this->name, 49, name, 49);
    }

    virtual void print() = 0;
};

class HourlyEmployee : public Employee
{
private:
    float hourlySalary;
public:


    HourlyEmployee()
    {
        hourlySalary = 0;
    }
    HourlyEmployee(char* name, float HourlySalary)
    {
        strncpy_s(this->name, 49, name, 49);
        this->hourlySalary = HourlySalary;
    }

    double getHourlySalary()
    {
        return hourlySalary;
        //cout << "What is your Hourly Salary" << endl;
        //cin >> HourlySalary;
    }

    void setHourlySalary(double HourlySalary)
    {
        this->hourlySalary = HourlySalary;
    }

    void print()
    {
        cout << "Hourly Employee Name: " << this->name << endl
            << "Salary: " << hourlySalary << " per hour" << endl;
    }

};

class SalariedEmployee : public Employee

{
private:
    float MonthlySalary;

public:

    SalariedEmployee()
    {
        MonthlySalary = 0;
    }

    SalariedEmployee(char* name, float MonthlySalary)
    {
        strncpy_s(this->name, 49, name, 49);
        this->MonthlySalary = MonthlySalary;
    }

    double getMonthlyySalary()
    {
        return MonthlySalary;
        //cout << "What is your Hourly Salary" << endl;
        //cin >> MonthlySalary;
    }

    void setMonthlySalary(double MonthlySalary)
    {
        this->MonthlySalary = MonthlySalary;
    }

    void print()
    {
        cout << "Hourly Employee Name: " << name << endl
            << "Salary: " << MonthlySalary << " per month" << endl;
    }

};

int main() 
{
    Employee * employee[2];
    employee[0] = new SalariedEmployee("Joe Bob", 4000);
    employee[1] = new HourlyEmployee("Jim Bob", 20);

    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
    {
        employee[i]->print();
    }

    for (size_t i = 0; i < 2; i++)
    {
        delete employee[i];
    }
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

First off,your `name` variable's gotta be of type char[50],not *char[50]. So I used `strncpy`(or the safe function `strncpy_s`) to copy the `name` in our constructor. Since you're dealing with chars,you cannot assign it like you did in some parts of your code,like this `name = name`. And I used `this->name` because the variable names are identical. Next off,in your main function you gotta have the `Employee` class and then assign it to an `HourlyEmployee` and `SalariedEmployee` , because those are the principles of polymorphism. Hope that I have helped you and if you have any questions,don't hesitate to ask.

`

Comment: Thank you for the response, I am going to review my mistakes now and I will let you know if I have any questions.